# React Checkbox to trigger regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Attaching my code - built using create-react-app.
Working on a small component for searching inputs. Highlight word if match and continue to display other text if not matched.

Current solution displays mark on all text once called.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const app = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [sensitive, setSensitive] = useState("i");
  let highlight = null;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };
  console.log(value);

  const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  };
  console.log(searchValue); 

  const getHighlightedText = (value, searchValue) => {
    let regex = new RegExp(`(${searchValue})`, `g${sensitive}`);
    console.log(regex);
    const parts = value.split(regex);
    //console.log(parts);
    highlight = <span> { parts.map((part, i) => 
        <span key={i} style={part === searchValue ? { backgroundColor: 'Yellow' } : {} }>
            { part }
        </span>)
    } </span>;
  }

  const checkedTest = () => {
    if(checked === true) {
      setSensitive(" ") // makes it case sensitive
      console.log(sensitive);
      setChecked(true);
    } else {
      setSensitive("i")
      console.log(sensitive);
      setChecked(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form className="text-search-form">
        <textarea className="source-text" value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input className="search-term" value={searchValue} onChange={handleSearchChange} onKeyPress={getHighlightedText(value, searchValue)} />
        <label htmlFor="caseSensitive">case sensitive?
          <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            className="case-sensitive" 
            name="caseSensitive" 
            defaultChecked={checked} 
            onClick={getHighlightedText(value, searchValue)}
            onChange={checkedTest} 
             />
        </label>
      </form>
      <div className="result">{highlight}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Highlighter;
```

Adjusted the code to display my proper component name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as expected

Removed all manual invocation of `getHighlightedText` and instead moved it to JSX and removed its parameters (May not be a good idea). The reason is that the values  `getHighlightedText` depends on are all in the function state and change of any would trigger a rerender which would automatically call this function.

Secondly, fixed your `checkedTest`, this is more cleaner.

Thirdly, the comparison you were doing in the iteration of parts wasn't case insensitive, so even if your regex was case insensitive, `===` of string isn't so, moved it to a seperate function and handled both cases. The insensitive case was handled by converting both part and searchvalue to a common case, in this case, lowercase.

As always, this can be improved so much more, but I think it solves your issues.

Demo:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-hermann-q6xce)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [sensitive, setSensitive] = useState("i");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSearchChange = event => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const getHighlightColor = part => {
    let isEqual = false;
    if (checked) {
      isEqual = part === searchValue;
    } else {
      isEqual = part.toLowerCase() === searchValue.toLowerCase();
    }
    return isEqual ? "Yellow" : "transperant";
  };

  const getHighlightedText = () => {
    let regex = new RegExp(`(${searchValue})`, `g${sensitive}`);
    const parts = value.split(regex);
    if (searchValue)
      return (
        <span>
          {parts.map((part, i) => (
            <span key={i} style={{ backgroundColor: getHighlightColor(part) }}>
              {part}
            </span>
          ))}
        </span>
      );
  };

  const checkedTest = event => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
    setSensitive(event.target.checked ? "" : "i");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <form className="text-search-form">
        <textarea
          className="source-text"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          className="search-term"
          value={searchValue}
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="caseSensitive">
          case sensitive?
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            className="case-sensitive"
            name="caseSensitive"
            defaultChecked={checked}
            onChange={checkedTest}
          />
        </label>
      </form>
      <div className="result">{getHighlightedText()}</div>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks for the help. The only thing I'm trying to figure out now is how I can display the value at all times. Then bring in the getHighlightedText() when a word is found. My conditional statement seems to not work properly. 

<div className="result">{getHighlightedText ? getHighlightedText() : {value}}</div>

Answer (score 0):

If you change following component and callback, it should work.
1) onChange callback, get the user selected option (true/false)
2) In the callback, call the search function.
Hope this helps.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  className="case-sensitive"
  name="caseSensitive"
  defaultChecked={checked}
  onChange={event => checkedTest(event.target.checked)}
/>;

const checkedTest = isChecked => {
  setChecked(isChecked);
  setSensitive(isChecked ? " " : "i");
  // call the getHighlightedText
  getHighlightedText(value, searchValue);
};
```